# Can I place ASP.NET user controls on pages without a control declaration?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls, web-config, declaration

I would like to put user controls on pages without registering the tag at the top of the page. For example:

```
<p>some text</p>
<myname:mycontrol runat="server" />
```

Is this possible? I've heard that tag declarations can be done in web.config... is this true?

If so, any idea which .NET framework versions support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in .net 2.0 web.config :

```
<pages>
    <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="MYPREFIX" namespace=="MyNamespace.Stuff" assembly="MyAssembly" />
```

Much more thorough discussion http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx